# Unable to uninstall an rpm on RHEL6

Tags: rhel, rpm, uninstall

I'm trying to remove a package from a system I am responsible for. Everytime I try it fails, though. The error it give is

```
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package vmware-open-vm-tools-xorg-utilities
```

I looked at the script using `rpm --scripts -qa vmware-open-vm-tools-xorg-utilities`. Looking at the scriptlet I'm interested in I see this:

```
preuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
if [ $1 -eq 0 ] && [ -e /usr/lib/vmware-tools/install/vmware-open-vm-tools-xorg-utilities ]; then
   # This is an uninstall
   /usr/lib/vmware-tools/install/vmware-open-vm-tools-xorg-utilities/installer uninstall
fi
```

Theoretically it should uninstall and, on several other servers, it has. This is the only server I'm having this issue on. Aside from above error I can't see anything else that would prevent this. The directory being sought exists and, as far as I can tell, no options are being passed to the scriptlet.

Anyone know what I should be looking at to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

While you could dive to the bottom of the pool on this, in this case, I'd say you should just tell RPM to skip that script:

```
# rpm -e --noscripts vmware-open-vm-tools-xorg-utilities
```

If that's not a "leaf" in the dependency graph, I'd force uninstall just that one package, then remove the others that depended on it without skipping scripts:

```
# rpm -e --nodeps vmware-open-vm-tools-$WHATEVER
```

It appears that the actual problem is that there are files missing that the `preun` script expects to be there, but I can't see the harm in ignoring this cleanup step.

After uninstalling everything, you might want to take a look in `/usr/lib/vmware-tools` and decide if there's anything left in there that you want to keep. If you're moving this VM to another VM host type entirely, you can probably just nuke it. If instead you're trying to upgrade to a different version of the VMware Tools, there might be things here that you want the later install to have.

Comment: Thanks. I had been trying to avoid using `rpm` directly since the server is managed via Satellite. Unfortunately, `yum` doesn't provide a means to get past these minor issues so I was forced to go the route you suggested.